# Emacs 24.2 installation make failure

Tags: emacs, failed-installation

Trying to install Emacs 24.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
./configure
```

worked fine.

make gives the error:

```
/usr/local/include/jmorecfg.h:263:16: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
image.c: In function ‘gif_load’:

image.c:7179:34: error: too few arguments to function ‘DGifOpenFileName’

/usr/local/include/gif_lib.h:177:14: note: declared here
image.c:7200:7: error: too few arguments to function ‘DGifOpen’
/usr/local/include/gif_lib.h:180:14: note: declared here
make[1]: \*** [image.o] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mark/Downloads/emacs-24.2/src'
make: \*** [src] Error 2
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Mark

Comment: you can install all dependent libraries by `aptitude build-dep emacs24
`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with your distribution but rather with the libraries you installed by hand.

/usr/local/include/jmorecfg.h
/usr/local/include/gif_lib.h
/usr/local/include/gif_lib.h

Are all in /usr/local which is never touched by any distribution but kept for your own personal binaries. It seems there is an incompatibility with the libgif headers you installed by hand.

Please try

```
./configure --without-gif
```

to verify and post your output again.